# How to create the gesture resizing functionality similar to Layout app for Instagram on Android?

Tags: android, gridview, layout, instagram, android-cardview

I want to implement the same dynamically creating layouts with the cells resizing like in the Layout app for Instagram: https://media.giphy.com/media/l0HlNCX30sTfsldAs/giphy.gif

Do anyone have idea how does it work?

Comment: It either changes the layout params of the views, or it uses a custom view for the entire container and then just redraws itself.

Comment: Can you share what you have tried so far? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far I`ve found this https://github.com/k9mail/splitview . I think I can to do something with that